# Extract subset of linearly independent columns from a matrix

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I have a Pandas dataframe of shape `(n,m)` where `n` is the number of observations and `m` is the number of features. The features all take boolean values `(0,1)` as they have been generated by one hot encoding categorical variables.

I would like to extract a subset of this matrix, whereby the columns that are linearly dependent (i.e. can be written as a linear combination of the other columns) are dropped.

I know of the existing threads regarding this question, however none of them are fully convincing. In particular, I would want to have an algorithm that leads to the same solution as this one in [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/77437-extract-linearly-independent-subset-of-matrix-columns):

```
function [Xsub,idx]=licols(X,tol)
%Extract a linearly independent set of columns of a given matrix X
%
%    [Xsub,idx]=licols(X)
%
%in:
%
%  X: The given input matrix
%  tol: A rank estimation tolerance. Default=1e-10
%
%out:
%
% Xsub: The extracted columns of X
% idx:  The indices (into X) of the extracted columns

   if ~nnz(X) %X has no non-zeros and hence no independent columns
       
       Xsub=[]; idx=[];
       return
   end

   if nargin<2, tol=1e-10; end
   

           
     [Q, R, E] = qr(X,0); 
     
     if ~isvector(R)
      diagr = abs(diag(R));
     else
      diagr = abs(R(1));   
     end

     %Rank estimation
     r = find(diagr >= tol*diagr(1), 1, 'last'); %rank estimation

     idx=sort(E(1:r));

     Xsub=X(:,idx);
```

I have tried running this function within Python using Jupyter Lab, but apparently the matlab engine does not work on new versions of Python (3.9.X).

Comment: There are only a half a dozen mathematical operations in the MATLAB function, did you make an attempt to rewrite it as a Python function?

Comment: Yes. I am unable to implement the QR decomposition [Q, R, E] = qr(X,0) in exactly the same way. I am also unable to install the MATLAB engine and run the MATLAB code directly in Python 3.X

Comment: You might get a more direct answer if you looked for / asked about replicating the QR decomp, with a specific [mcve].